# Running a command on remote machine without ssh delay

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I want to establish an API server with a load balancer. I will use one machine as the master which will assign tasks in a round robin manner to 2 slave machines. All machines are hosted in AWS.

In order to process the request, I need to run a python script. When the master receives the request, it can trigger the command on one of the slaves using ssh but this adds an extra couple of seconds delay to the processing time.

Is there a way to reduce/remove the ssh delay?

Comment: [SSH Multiplexing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing) is the solution. It can be also persistent connection for some time depending on the setup.

Comment: @Jakuje Would you please elaborate on this a bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you have something implemented or you just collect the thoughts.

The basic use case is described on [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing), but the easiest is to set up public key authentication and `ssh_config` (config for `machine2` would be almost the same):

```
Host machine1
  HostName machine1.example.org
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/controlmasters/%r@%h:%p
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPersist yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa-something
```

And then call the remote script like this:

```
ssh machine1 ./remote_script.py
```

First `ssh` call will initiate the connection (and will take a bit longer), every other script call will use the existing connection and will be almost immediate.

If you are using Python, the similar behaviour you can achieve using `paramiko` or even `ansible` if you want to step one level up (but really depends on use case).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jakuje. What should be the control master file? How do I create it?

Comment: It is created automatically by SSH. It just should be in safe path that is not accessible by others.

Comment: I got it work by creating a folder ~/.ssh/controlmasters. Thanks a lot for this. Now every call, barring the first one is very quick.

I have just one more doubt. Is using ssh to run this command faster than if a HTTP server was running on the slave and master machine would use that?

Comment: Yes. For creating HTTP request, you need to establish TCP connection. When using ControlMaster, the connection is already established and you basically just send the command.

Comment: Just before ending the discussion, using ssh multiplexing, is there a limit on the number of times I can ssh into a machine?

Also, how do I finally close the ssh session?

Comment: No, there is no such limit. Only limit you can set up on the server is maximum of parallel connections using `MaxSessions` option in `sshd_config`. If you want to close the connection use `ssh -O stop machine1` or `exit` instead of stop to remove existing socket and all the connections.